# Can't get Lamar (IOC) to resolve API Controller Dependencies in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap, .net-core-3.1, lamar

I am getting an error when trying to call the controller below using Lamar to resolve the dependencies at runtime.

I have tried `.AddControllersAsServices()` and without and still get the same result.

Using

- ASP.NET Core: 3.1
- Lamar

`Container.GetInstance<IDataAccess>()` works inside the watch window but will not resolve at runtime

`Container.WhatDoIHave()` also shows that the dependency is there

**Question?**
What am I missing in Lamar configuration to resolve the controllers?

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IDataAccess _dataAccess;
    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(IDataAccess dataAccess, ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _dataAccess = dataAccess;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return _dataAccess.GetAll();
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public IContainer Container { get; private set; }

    public void ConfigureContainer(ServiceRegistry services)
    {
        Container = new Container(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.Scan(scanner =>
            {
                scanner.AssembliesAndExecutablesFromApplicationBaseDirectory(a =>
                    a.FullName.Contains("Test3.1"));
                scanner.WithDefaultConventions();
                scanner.SingleImplementationsOfInterface();
            });
        });

        services
            .AddControllers(options =>
            {
                // Disable automatic fallback to JSON
                options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;

                // Honor browser's Accept header (e.g. Chrome)
                options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
            })
            .AddControllersAsServices();

        services.AddMvc()
            .AddControllersAsServices();

        Container.WhatDidIScan();
        Container.WhatDoIHave();

        Console.Write("Container Instantiated");
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseLamar()
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder
                    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .UseIISIntegration()
                    .UseStartup<Startup>();

            });
}
```

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> LamarException: Cannot build registered instance weatherForecastController of 'Test3._1.Controllers.WeatherForecastController':
>    Cannot fill the dependencies of any of the public constructors
>    Available constructors:new WeatherForecastController(IDataAccess dataAccess, `ILogger<Test3._1.Controllers.WeatherForecastController>` logger)
>    * IDataAccess is not registered within this container and cannot be auto discovered by any missing family policy

Comment: The error message indicates that the container can't resolve the controller's dependencies. Make sure those dependencies are registered with the container so it knows how to resolve them when activating controllers

Comment: You are configuring separate containers in your Startup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicates that the container can't resolve the controller's dependencies. Make sure those dependencies are registered with the container so it knows how to resolve them when activating controllers.

This is because separate containers are being configured in `Startup` and the one used by the framework is unaware of `IDataAccess` as the `Scan` was not applied to its container.

#### Reference [Lamar - Integration with ASP.Net Core](https://jasperfx.github.io/lamar/documentation/ioc/aspnetcore/)

```
public class Startup {

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    //REMOVED IContainer. It is not needed

    public void ConfigureContainer(ServiceRegistry services) {

        //Apply scan to the registry used by framework so container is aware of types.
        services.Scan(scanner => {
            scanner.AssembliesAndExecutablesFromApplicationBaseDirectory(a =>
                a.FullName.Contains("Test3.1"));
            scanner.WithDefaultConventions();
            scanner.SingleImplementationsOfInterface();
        });

        services
            .AddControllers(options => {
                // Disable automatic fallback to JSON
                options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
                // Honor browser's Accept header (e.g. Chrome)
                options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
            })
            .AddControllersAsServices();

        services.AddMvc()
            .AddControllersAsServices();

        services.WhatDidIScan();
        services.WhatDoIHave();

        Console.Write("Container Instantiated");
    }

    //...omitted for brevity
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem, you were totally right. I got bogged down into thinking that I had to create a Container on my end not realizing that .UseLamar() was doing that for me. I appreciate you being so quick to respond and helpful. Thanks!